# Intellij - open project shortcut stopped working after update

Tags: intellij-idea, command-line-interface

I've just update Intellij to version using JetBrain TOOLBOX and for some reason the `idea` cli command used to open a project from the shell doesn't work anymore.

The error that I get is:

```
The file /Users/myUser/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/183.4886.37/IntelliJ IDEA.app does not exist.
```

If I try to check what is inside the folder:

```
/Users/myUser/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/
```

I can only find something like that:

```
ch-0 ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  9 myUser  staff   288B Sep  2 15:53 192.5728.98
drwxr-xr-x  9 myUser  staff   288B Sep  2 15:53 192.6262.58
```

So the file is effectively missing.

I've tried to enable shell script inside TOOLBOX (for Intellij obviously) but still doesn't work.
It look like there is this path arcoded somewhere and I cannot change it using TOOLBOX.

I use the command `idea` pretty often in the shell so I'd really like to restore this functionality.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `I've tried to enable shell script inside TOOLBOX (for Intellij obviously) but still doesn't work` Have you specified the [shell script location](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eyibaucv2ypak1u/shell_script_location.png?dl=0) (this the directory must be present in OS $PATH)?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the command line shell script and location in Toolbox settings:

[image: Shell script location]

The script name can be also changed per IDE:

[image: Script name]

Try deleting any existing scripts and let Toolbox install the updated versions.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Choose the scripts location,then click the `change` buttom,it works